# Grpc client on Net 6 doesn't connect with grpc server on Net 4.8

Tags: c#, grpc

When client and server work on same pc they connect fine.

Next situation is server on real pc, client on VirtualBox. Both devices have Windows 10. Firewall is disabled on server. When client tries to connet to server exception occurs:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error
> starting gRPC call.

Client code:

```
public ThermocyclerClient()
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);       
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator 
    };
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://192.168.111.189:7001", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });
    client = new ThermocyclerRpcService.ThermocyclerRpcServiceClient(channel);
}
```

Server code:

```
server = new Server 
{
    Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", 7001, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }, 
    
    Services = 
    {
        ExtractorRpcService.BindService(this.extractorService),
        ThermocyclerRpcService.BindService(this.thermocyclerService)
    }
};
```

Why client can't connect to server?

Real pc and VirtualBox ping each over successfully.

Comment: does the server have an open firewall rule for inbound TCP connections on 7001?

Comment: also: the server *appears* to be specifying host "localhost"; should you actually be binding to the machine name instead? the inbound requests won't be to "localhost" (honestly, though, I'd recommend using "current" .net for the server, i.e. Kestrel with gRPC enabled)

Comment: I tried to connect with disabled firewall.

Comment: Try to use "0.0.0.0" instead of localhost. This way, you should tell the server to listen on any ip and not only on localhost. Never tried it tho.

Comment: @Mark Gravel, you are right. Changing from localhost to computer name has helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer was given by Marc Gravell in comments. Changing from localhost to computer name has helped. "0.0.0.0" in host name also works (thanks to zanseb).